# ZendeskApi.Tickets.CreateTicket throws 401 despite "Anybody can submit tickets" is enabled

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-api

I have a Trial subscription and I'm using ZendeskApi.Tickets.CreateTicket(ticket) to create a new ticket; Anybody can submit tickets is Enabled. It works when I create a ticket with requester.email that is a registered user, but I'm getting the below error when I try to create a ticket with a Requester who is not a user. Tips on what I'm doing wrong?

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.Error content: {"error":"Couldn't authenticate you"}
Resource String: tickets.json +
Body: {
"ticket": {
"subject": "Subject",
"comment": {
"body": "Message test body",
"public": false
},
"requester": {
"email": "wendellj@gmail.com"
},
"is_public": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anonymous user you should use this api end point: https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/requests#create-request

This is used to create requests in zendesk when user is not registered with user and it doesn't need authentication header as well. See

> To make anonymous requests:
>
> - Omit the authorization header.
> - Include a requester object in the request object.